# How to calculate a course ranking

Tags: classification, ranking

I thought I was good at statistics until I found myself drowning in a simple problem that I have difficulty solving, hence my appeal for your expertise :)

1. A test has been administered to many candidates.
2. The number of candidates is >20,000. c1, c2, c3 ... C20000+
3. Each candidate has been ranked on the test result and there are no 2 candidates with equal ranking. vote: r1, r2, r3... r20000
4. There are 5 courses s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 that the candidates have expressed a choice for. The highest ranking candidate fills the places in his highest choice until all the places for the 20 courses are filled.
5. The number of places in each course "s" is different: s1=50, s2=70 s3=10, s4=200, s5=20. Sum of places= 350

What ranking system would you use to rank the popularity or demand of the courses by the successful candidates?

It is very easy to rank the demand/popularity of each course by summing the choices for each course of all the 20,000+ candidates, but this gives me the demand index for the population at large. I want the rankings that derive from the successful 350 applicants.

The idea is to obtain a ranking as expressed by the choices of the SUCCESSFUL applicants.

Can you help me?

PS: My lame attempts at solving this problem were:
A) sum the ranking of the candidates that succeeded in each course and divide it by the number of places in the course.

B) Summed the candidate ranking  mutiplied it by the rank within the course and divided this amount by the total places in the course eg candidate 203 was the 5th in the S2 course(which has 70 places): (203*5 +...for all the 70 candidates)/70

Comment: Welcome to the list. If this is homework, please add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Oh no, this is not homework..I wish it was  :)

Comment: How do the students express their preferences? Do they say "yes"/"no" to each course? Do they just pick one? Do they rate the courses?

Comment: It appears to be standard bookwork ("*A test has been administered...*"), as might be done for the purpose of study, whether formally set as homework or not. If it's for some subject, or even for your own personal study. please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Alternatively, could you explain how the question arises?

Comment: Hi Peter! Yes the students express a choice of any or all of the courses and of course, they are attributed the choice according to their ranking. The choice expression is a simple 1,2, 3,4 5.

Comment: Hi Glen. I am glad it "seems" like homework because the answers will be easy.Nature of the enquiry is to help students that are competing in a nationwide test to be informed of the popularity of their choices before they make their choice.I have come up with a ranking of my own, bit it seems to be too simple. For example if one course has the first candidate r1 (the top student in the test) and the last student that has elected for that course is r18000, I would like the calculated ranking to take this "large" spread into account. Not sure if I am making much sense :(

Comment: If somebody wants to have the excel database with the data and you give me an email, I am only too happy to supply it:) In this case be informed that my question above is a simplified version of the real life problem. The choices expressed exceed one milion and the candidates are over  70000 and the courses are over 70 with total places over 10000. :( Hence the need of a reliable, verifiable and preferably "proportional" ranking index/system/algorithm for each course :)

Comment: It seems that my problem is either too easy or too difficult :( Or perhaps I have posted it in the wrong section? :(

Comment: I'm not clear on whether everyone gets to give their ranking for all courses and then gets into the course they gave the highest ranking as long as it still has a place free? Or can you only pick 1, 2, 3.. courses? Depending, there's few options that could summarize the data and provide some perspectives, .e.g. 1) mean rank of the admitted for each course by the top 350 candidate, 2) rank of the lowest candidate that got into the course, 3) for how many of the admitted candidates (to any course) this was the top-1 choice, a top-2 choice, a top-3 choice etc.?

Comment: 4) How many people picked this course and failed to get a place in any course, but would have got a place if they had picked a different course instead of it? (if that's an option) 5) How many people picked this course and got a place in it when all their other choices were already taken? (if that's an option)